# New dev team, existing app, can't view data

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been tasked with creating a new version of an existing app.  The previous development team (external contractors) have disappeared so am having trouble at the moment..

The existing app stores user data locally.  The new version of the app I have to develop needs to keep the existing user data.  I was wondering if it was possible for my app to access it?

I have looked in the following folders:

```
/data/data/theapp/databases
/data/data/theapp/files
```

Only the data added by my app was in those directories.
I have been unable to look at

```
/data/data
```

Please note:
After installing the existing app and recording data, then installing my app via Android Studio, the existing app disappears.  Is this due to build string for both apps being the same?

The client who has given me this task may be able to obtain certain information so if there's anything I need, could you point it out please?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if it was possible for my app to access it?

Only if it is the same app, defined as:

- having the same application ID (or package name if you are not changing the application ID in your Gradle build files, if any)
- signed by the same signing key

> After installing the existing app and recording data, then installing my app via Android Studio, the existing app disappears. Is this due to build string for both apps being the same?

Presumably. However, in that case, you would appear to meet the aforementioned criteria, which means you have access to whatever the old app's data was. You will need to read the source code of the old app to determine where it is storing that data.

Comment: Thank you, after getting the signing key, was able to generate a signed apk with it which updated the app, keeping the application data intact :)